# How to remove Actionbar In MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui, maui-community-toolkit

My XAML Code for view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         BackgroundColor="White"
         Title=""
         x:Class="Chuxi.MainPage">

<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Center">



    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have Tried C# Code TO Remove BUt Doesnt Working

```
public MainPage()
 {
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    InitializeComponent();
 }
```

How Can I Remove Title Bar And Make It Full Screen View

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This May Help You. Its working For me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         BackgroundColor="White"
         Title=""
         x:Class="Chuxi.MainPage">

<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Center">



    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Any Issue ask me on comment. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hide the action bar programmatically with the code below

```
AppShell.SetNavBarIsVisible(this, false);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76305006/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).